# Homebrew cannot install anything: Caused by some SSL related problem with cURL

Tags: macos, shell, curl, command-line, homebrew

Homebrew stopped to work. Here is an error that I get when I try to `brew install anything`:

```
$ brew install python
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gdbm-1.18.1_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz

curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
Error: Failed to download resource "gdbm"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gdbm-1.18.1_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
```

Here is the output of `brew doctor` & `brew update`:

```
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

The problem seems to be with `curl` command, so I tried just `curl` with same result:

```
curl https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gdbm-1.18.1_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

I am not behind proxy. What does this mean and how to fix it?

Comment: I had the same problem. But I was behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `gdbm` trying to install Python, but `brew doctor` gave a hint about `ca-certificates`. I did

```
brew install ca-certificates openssl@3
```

and the issue was resolved.